# How to enforce Connect-AzureAD in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-powershell

I have a PowerShell script to get the Object ID of the Service Principal using the Get-AzureADServicePrincipal command. To run this "Get-AzureADServicePrincipal" command, running "Connect-AzureAD" command is mandatory. When I'm trying to add the code using "Connect-AzureAD" through Azure devOps, I get the error "Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation".

Comment: Yes the answers are helpful. selecting one as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because when you run `Connect-AzureAD`, there is a login prompt that comes up in order to enter in the login credentials.

So the workaround would be pass on the credentials - using the `-Credentials` switch.

**Sample Script**

```
#Creating Credentials
string]$userName = 'MyUserName'
[string]$userPassword = 'MySuperSecurePassword'

# Convert to SecureString
[securestring]$secStringPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $userPassword -AsPlainText -Force
[pscredential]$credObject = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($userName, $secStringPassword)


#Connecting to the Azure AD
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $credObject
```

So this, will suppress the Pop up at the same time facilitate the login.

You will not be provided with the login pop up - also the error.

**Note :**
This may not work if you have the account used for logging is MFA enabled.

Answer (score 0):

`Connect-AzureAD` by default will prompt you for login and password in pop up window.

Inside Azure DevOps `Connect-AzureAD` by default stacks waiting for input from user and pipeline never finishes, as user cannot input anything.

You can try to run the following script in Azure PowerShell script task：

```
Install-Module -Name "AzureAD" -Force
$context = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile.DefaultContext
$graphToken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, "https://graph.microsoft.com").AccessToken
$aadToken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, "https://graph.windows.net").AccessToken
Write-Output "Hi I'm $($context.Account.Id)"
Connect-AzureAD -AadAccessToken $aadToken -AccountId $context.Account.Id -TenantId $context.tenant.id
```

This solution is provided by this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60185213/automate-connect-azuread-using-powershell-in-azure-devops). In addition, this ticket also provides a solution using `-Credential $Credential` You can refer to it for details.